# dpkg: warning: package "libglib2.0-data"

Tags: apt, dpkg, samba

I have such a problem with the update

```
dpkg: ostrzeżenie: brak listy plików pakietu "libglib2.0-data", przyjęcie że pakiet nie ma zainstalowanych plików
dpkg: nienaprawialny błąd krytyczny, przerywanie:
 lista plików pakietu "samba-libs:i386" nie zawiera kończącej pustej linii
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)



dpkg: warning: package "libglib2.0-data" file list missing, assuming package has no files installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, abort:
  the list of files for package "samba-libs: i386" does not contain a trailing empty line
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (2)
```